# Prove that $n \ge 401$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

There are $n$ students at Petra High School. It is known that every Petra student knows exactly
$20$ other students (if $A$ knows $B$, then $B$ knows $A$). A set of $k> 2$
students $(s_1, s_2, \ldots, s_k)$ are said to be $k$-cyclic if $s_i$ and $s_{i + 1}$ know each other
for every $i \in \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$, where $s_{n + 1} = s_1$. It is known that there is a collection
students who form a $5$-cycle, but there is no group of students who form
$3$-cycle and $4$-cycle. Prove that $n \ge 401$

> *i don't know the right tag for this problem, please someone change the tag!

I hope someone can help me to solve it, I'm too confused where to start,
If someone can solve it is really great, I am very grateful!

Comment: maybe what is meant is, for example $ s_a $ must know exactly $20$ other students? for example $\{s_1, s_2, ..., s_{20}\}$, with $s_a\ne s_1 \ne s_2 \ne ... \ne s_{20}$

Comment: Considering the graph $G$ of students we know that $G$ is an $n$-regular graph. Maybe show that such a graph with $n^2$ or fewer vertices must have a $3$ or $4$ cycle.

Comment: Too many questions begin or end with "I don't even know how to begin with this problem". While this may be true ... it is still not a valid reason to limit your post to the statement of the problem without any mention of your own thoughts. – From [Avoid “no clue” questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933/42969)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to calculate the number of unordered pair of students $(a, b)$ where either $a$ is friend with $b$ or there exists a student $c$ that is the friend of $a$ and $b$ simultaneously. For such pair, both can't be true simultaneously because then $(a,b,c)$ will form a $3$-cycle, so the number is the sum of each conditions number.

The number of pair $(a, b)$ where $a$ is friend with $b$ is $20n/2=10n$ because everyone has exactly $20$ friends, and $20n$ counts both $(a, b)$ and $(b, a)$.

Student pair $(a, b)$ cannot have more than one mutual friend, because then those friends $c, d$ will make a $4$-cycle $(a, c, b, d)$. So counting from the side of mutual friend, everyone induces $20 \cdot 19/2$ pairs by picking two people from each person friends list. So we have $190n$ such pairs total.

Summing both we have the number of pair with the conditions as many as $200n$, but totally there are only $n(n-1)/2$ pairs of students. So we have $200n \leq n(n-1)/2$ which makes $n \geq 401$.